# 2 criterias in the same query

Tags: mysql, select

i need some help...

In the same query can i have 2 different criteria?

Ex: I need to select, **product type**, **product color** and **product price** between 1000 to 2000.

In this research 10 products for example will be shown, and i would like to continue showing other products only with the **price** criterion.

The first 10 products are on the correct criteria and other products will be displayed with the **price** criterion.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: yes it is, show us what you'll try

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You have to separate your criterias with `AND` :

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE product_type = 'something' AND product_color = 'something' AND product_rate > 1000 AND product_rate < 2000
```